# Vuex action - записать ответ промиса в переменную

Tags: javascript, axios, vuex, асинхронность

Есть экшн.

```
messageLastDate: (context, state) => {
            axios.get('api/messageLastDate').then(response => {
                let lastMessage = response.data
            });

            console.log(lastMessage);
        },
```

В lastMessage записывается промис,потому что код вывода происходит раньше, чем промис решается, это я уже понял. Но мне необходимо значение промиса в переменной, так как я хочу в этой функции с ним еще работать.
Как это реализовать,может по аналогии с вызовом мутации есть какие то свойсва типа context.подожди_запиши_в_переменную? Или только каким нибудь сеттаймаутом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

`async` указывает, что функция является асинхронной. `await` приостанавливает выполнение функции, до получения результата, поэтому в `response` лежит результат, а не `Promise`

Важно, что `await` можно использовать только внутри асинхронных функций.

```
messageLastDate: async (context, state) => {
    const response = await axios.get('api/messageLastDate');
    let lastMessage = response.data;
    console.log(lastMessage);
},
```